# How to update the element type with button press PySimpleGui. Example. Change a checkbox to a text element

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am working on a project where the user is given a grid of checkboxes. When the user selects a box and clicks a button, the checkbox needs to become uncheckable. I know that I can update the visibility of the box but I want to know if there is a way I can change the checkbox type to a text element? Or a way I can leave the element as a checkbox and leave the text associated with it visible, while making the actual box uncheckable?

Comment: element.update(disabled=True) ?

Comment: Disabled will more or less do what I want. I didnt see a disabled param in the doc. Thanks. I was more looking for a way to change the actual type of an element from checkbox to text but this will work too. Thanks